# inserting passwords into pass from shell-mode

Tags: shell-mode, passwords

I'm trying to manage my passwords using the [pass](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pass) script from `shell-mode` inside Emacs. The script prompts me to enter the password twice as is customary when adding or changing passwords. The first time it asks for the password, Emacs successfully hides it, placing little dots in the message area. This is the desired behavior. Unfortunately, the second time it asks for the password, Emacs happily prints the characters to the `shell-mode` buffer. Is there a configuration setting I can add to make sure it hides the password both times?

Comment: Also, have you considered using the [password-store.el](http://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/emacs/password-store.el) frontend to `pass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure `comint-password-prompt-regexp` so that it includes whatever text `pass` gives at the second prompt.

Alternative answer, instead of just typing the password, you could type `M-x send-invisible RET enter-the-password RET`.